# How can I show that if $A\subseteq B$ then $|A|\le|B| $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is the progress I made.

If  $A\subseteq B$ then it is either $|A|\lt|B| $ or $|A|=|B|$.

For the first case  $f: A\rightarrow B$ must be an injective function and it does not necessarily need to be surjective. For the second case, however, the function $f$ must be bijective. Therefore, $|A|\le|B| $ must hold whenever $A\subseteq B$.

I feel like my reasoning is circular and hence does not prove anything. I would appreciate to know if that is case and to see the correct proof. Thanks.

Comment: A function $f:A\to B$ may not necessarily be injective. You need to construct an explicit example of an injective function from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: If $f : A \rightarrow B$ is not injective how can A be a subset of B?

Comment: @melihartar An injective functions $f$ definitely exists, but not every function $f$ is necessarily injective, you need to think of an example of a function which is injective and satisfies your conditions. The fact that $ A \subset eq B $ means that there's a very simple example of such a function.

Comment: If $A\subseteq B$ then the *inclusion* $A\to B$ prescribed by $a\mapsto a$ is injective. Conclusion: $|A|\leq|B|$. Isn't that all you need? I think that your $f$ is meant to be the inclusion, but you did not mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it's perfectly trivial:

If $A \subseteq B$, define $f: A \to B$ to be $f(x) = x$, which is well-defined by the inclusion.

This $f$ is clearly injective : $f(x) = f(x')$ immediately implies (equals really) $x=x'$. So we have an injective map from $A$ into $B$ and this shows $|A| \le |B|$ by definition.

That's all there is to it, really.